# Golden Gate realtime replication basic question

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-12c, goldengate

1. I have a task to replicate unidirectional real time data from source database A to target database B. I do not need all the table from A, only few tables and few columns inside those tables. Say 10 tables and 30 columns from A go into 6 tables on database B.

Is this doable in Golden Gate (GG)? Oracle 11g source and 12c target DB version in same OS version.

2. In addition to the above, when GG is replicating can it insert a sequence number on a column/table in database B?

Any links you can point, as how to do the above is very much appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this doable in GoldenGate(GG)?

The `Map` or `Table` parameter can be used to select Table, depending on whether to apply in Extract or in Replicat.

The `Cols` and `ColsEXCEPT` attributes of the `Table` parameter can be used for Columns selection.

I believe that the Oracle's official documentation is good link to create the solution.

Here are some.

[Selecting Table](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/gg_parameters160.htm#GWURF546)

[Selecting Columns](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWUAD/wu_datainteg.htm#GWUAD443)

[SQLEXEC:Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/gg_parameters156.htm)

Comment: Would the SQLEXEC do step #2 for me?

Comment: In addition to this, to have a sequence on only the secondary/replicated data, GG doesn't do this for you, but you can do it yourself. You just need to add the column to the secondary server, and create a trigger to populate it using a sequence

Answer (score 0):

I came to know from Oracle, inserting a sequence is possible with inserting the same sequence at the source as well, called cyclic sequence. For more details check the MOS doc "Implementing replication of cyclic sequences in GoldenGate (Doc ID 1321558.1)".